# Is a question about ADC (analog to digital) conversion really off-topic here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, reopen-closed

The following question got closed just after being posted: [What is the formula to convert the result of an 8-bit ADC to voltage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476333/8-bit-a-d-conversion-chip)

I'm the one who had (barely) the time to answer it (first as comments, then moved to an actual answer).

As asked, once understood it's "just" about simple maths (application of the rule of three).

But I don't think it would be answered on the maths forum (what are 8 bits? what is an ADC?) nor on the electronics forum (it's about getting into the digital domain, i.e. giving access to **software**).

Stack Overflow even has an [adc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adc) tag, and allows other computer engineering questions like [ADXL345 Accelerometer data use on I2C (Beaglebone Black)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60289453/adxl345-accelerometer-data-use-on-i2c-beaglebone-black)

As a computer engineer myself, I consider this forum was the correct one to use. Even if it has nothing to do with cloud / databases / web and the likes, it is a question I have to answer to be able to do my hardware programming (embedded) job! As is the question about the I2C bus to another ADC, even if it's not about the "more common" Ethernet bus, and as are most of the questions about programmable devices (my main focus).

Anyone think the same? Or is there yet another Stack Exchange site (not mathematics nor electronics (actually called "electrical engineering")) where that question, and any question about access to device registers, would likely be answered?

Comment: The question isn’t about the I2C bus. If it were a software question about communication over I2C, that would be on-topic. This is just conversion from ADC units into voltage, which is what you’d find by reading the data sheet for the electronic component. Basic electrical engineering, not programming.

Answer (score 17):

1. This isn't a forum; please don't think of it quite like that.  There's similarities with forums that this site has, but we're definitely not the same.
2. Yes, this is an Electrical Engineering-type question.  It *might* be better suited on [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Do your homework to see if it'd fit.
3. I'm a software developer and architect.  If someone mentions voltage to me, I have a minor panic attack and wonder if I need to hire an electrician.

Comment: Unlike Makoto, I’m a software developer and architect who deals with ADCs and voltage measurements literally all day long. (Okay, sometimes they give me minor panic attacks, too, but it’s not for lack of familiarity.) Anyway, I still think this question is off-topic for SO, despite being something that I work with day in and day out. This *specific* question isn’t about working with ADCs or sampling in a *software development* context. It’s just about a formula, which is more related to electronics and hardware. I’ve migrated it to EE. Other questions about ADCs may be perfectly on-topic here.